# Address Matching Code with Accurate Scoring

Tags: python

I am attempting to develop a code that compares two addresses using multiple conditions and calculates a score based on the numbers and alphabets present in the addresses. The goal is to create two separate "buckets" for numbers and alphabets, then determine a score based on certain criteria. Specifically, the score will be 100 if the numbers in both addresses are identical in terms of sequence and placement. For alphabets, we will use a fuzzy matching approach to calculate the score.

In the current code, everything appears to be working correctly except for the comparison of numbers. Even when the numbers are not in the same positions in both addresses, a score of 100 is being generated instead of 0.

```py
import re

def extract_elements(address):
    """Extracts numerical and alphabetical elements from the address."""
    elements = re.findall(r'(\d+|\D+)', address)
    return elements

def calculate_element_similarity(element1, element2):
    """Calculates similarity between two elements (numerical or alphabetical)."""
    if element1 == element2:
        return 100.00
    elif element1.isdigit() and element2.isdigit():
        # If both elements are numerical, check if they have the same sequence.
        return 100.00 if element1 == element2 else 0.00
    elif not element1.isdigit() and not element2.isdigit():
        # If both elements are alphabetical, consider them similar.
        return 100.00 if element1 == element2 else 0.00
    else:
        # Use fuzzy string matching for alphabetical elements.
        return 0.00

def address_similarity(addr1, addr2):
    """Computes similarity between two addresses based on their elements."""
    elements1 = extract_elements(addr1)
    elements2 = extract_elements(addr2)

    if not elements1 or not elements2:
        return 0.00, []  # If both addresses have no elements, similarity is 0.

    num_elements = min(len(elements1), len(elements2))
    bucket_scores = []

    for i in range(num_elements):
        element1 = elements1[i]
        element2 = elements2[i]

        bucket_similarity = calculate_element_similarity(element1, element2)
        bucket_scores.append((element1, element2, bucket_similarity))

    # Calculate the overall similarity score based on all elements except for the last one.
    total_similarity = sum([score for _, _, score in bucket_scores[:-1]])
    similarity = total_similarity / (num_elements - 1) if num_elements > 1 else 0.00

    return similarity, bucket_scores

# Test examples
address1 = "123 ABC 12 456 XYZ"
address2 = "123 ABC 12 WYZ 456"
similarity_score, bucket_scores = address_similarity(address1, address2)

print("Bucket Similarity Scores:")
for element1, element2, score in bucket_scores:
    print(f"Element1: {element1 if element1.isdigit() else element2}, Similarity: {score:.2f}")

print(f"\nOverall Similarity Score Calculation:")
for element1, element2, score in bucket_scores:
    print(f"{element1 if element1.isdigit() else element2}: {score:.2f}", end=" + ")
print(f"= {similarity_score:.2f}")
```

Comment: from the above code, I am getting the below result
Bucket Similarity Scores:
Element1: 123, Similarity: 100.00
Element1:  ABC , Similarity: 100.00
Element1: 12, Similarity: 100.00
Element1:  WYZ , Similarity: 0.00
Element1: 456, Similarity: 100.00

Overall Similarity Score Calculation:
123: 100.00 +  ABC : 100.00 + 12: 100.00 +  WYZ : 0.00 + 456: 100.00 + = 75.00

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting this answer is because the reutrn value of the `extract_elements()` function provided in the example is this:

```
element 1: ['123', ' ABC ', '12', ' ', '456', ' XYZ']
element 2: ['123', ' ABC ', '12', ' WYZ ', '456']
```

so you can see that the lists are of different lengths meaning that the item `456` are both at the same list intdex. **(index = 4)**.

So you would need to modify the function accordingly to return a desired list...

FYI: i discovered this by simply adding print statements inside the `address_similarity` to observe (inspect) the lists.